# C. Comparing first character of a structure field to array elements in a loop. SIGSEGV

Tags: c, arrays, structure

My approach that does it's job (in my compiler at least) but has a SIGSEGV signal (postmortem report). I want to understand what's happening wrong. 
 
Function prints "an" or "a", depending on the p->field first char. 
example of what function may display (a/an):

```
Jack was an Astronaut
```

or

```
Jack was a Solider
```

```
void display(const struct student_t* p)
{
    const char vovel[] = "aoeiuAOEIU";
    char article[3] = "a";
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<sizeof(vovel); i++) {
        if (p->field[0]==vovel[i]) //<-------here it detects SIGSEGV.
            strcpy(article, "an");
    }
    if (p!=NULL)
        printf("%s was %s %s\n", p->name, article, p->field);
}
```

The Structure can be like:

```
struct student_t
{
    char name[20];
    char field[50];
};
```

What is wrong with that? 
I'm thinking that maybe what I made wrong is the way I access first sign of p->field... Or maybe it has something to do with the last sign of my vovel array which is '\0'..? 
Or can it be that SIGSEGV is caused by another part of my program, but is detected here instead? I used similar loop elsewhere, clang detected "Out of bound memory access (access exceeds upper limit of memory block) -- Logic error bug" in this other loop (posted below) that I based my "vovel" detecting function on...

```
const char* find(const char * start, char **end, char **next, const char *delims) {
    static const char blanks[] = " \t\r";
    start += strspn(start, blanks);
    *end=NULL;
    *end = strpbrk(start, delims); //<-- cpp check: Either the condition 'end==0' is redundant or there is possible null pointer dereference: end. -- warning
    if (end == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    *next = *(end) + 1;
    while(*end > start) {
        bool found = false;
        for (unsigned int i=0; i<sizeof(blanks); i++) {
            if ((*end)[-1] == blanks[i]) { //<-- clang: Out of bound memory access (access exceeds upper limit of memory block) -- Logic error bug
                --*end ;
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) break;
    }
    return start;
}
```

Thanks a lot for all the help!

Comment: Where do you call `display`? Smells like a plain old "didn't initialize the variable" bug.

Comment: try to put: `assert(p != NULL); assert(p->field != NULL);` in the beginning of display function.

Comment: `for (unsigned int i=0; i<sizeof(vovel); i++)` This does btw read one byte too many, needlessly checking the null terminator of `vovel[i]`. Should be `sizeof vovel-1`. Not the bug you were looking for but still a bug.

Comment: Also, you can use `strpbrk` function, it's as simple as `void display(const struct student_t* p) { printf("%s was a%s %s\n", p->name, strpbrk((char[2]){p->field[0],'\0'}, "aoeiuAOEIU") == NULL ? "" : "n", p->field); }`

Comment: @KamilCuk: [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) would be even simpler.

Comment: Och right, I didn't think of switching arguments, `strchr("aoeiuAOEIU", p->field[0])`

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk and @DevSolar, `printf("%s was a%s %s\n", p->name,strchr("aoeiuAOEIU", p->field[0]) == NULL ? "" : "n", p->field);` seems to be solving my SEGSIGV problem. Could you please tell me how do you call using this "kinda_if ? yes : no" construction with ?: ? I want to google it but don't know how to name it

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator 
 https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.5.15